# How to format biblatex bibliography reference in TOC?

Tags: biblatex, memoir

I'm using the memoir class with biblatex and having trouble formatting the bibliography reference in the TOC to match the other references. (I want it like the chapters--centered and the same font.) Below is my MWE. I added `addcontentsline` for the bibliography but it was ignored so I commented it out.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\ordinal\relax

% Bibliography
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    hyperref=auto,
    style=authoryear,
    backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

% TOC title
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\HUGE\textit{Contents}}

% Chapter
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{\hspace*{10pt}\huge#1\cftparfillskip\par}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{}
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\hfil\Large\emph{#1}\hfil\strut\huge\par\nopagebreak\hfil}

% Document
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents*
    \chapter*[Introduction]{Introduction}
    \chapter{The First Chapter}
    "Everything is relative" (\cite{einstein}).
    \chapter{The Second Chapter}

    \phantomsection
    \printbibliography\newpage
%    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberline{}References}
\end{document}
```

The `sample.bib` file is

```
@article{einstein,
    author = "Albert Einstein",
    title = "On the electrodynamics of moving bodies",
    journal = "Annalen der Physik",
}
```

Comment: Did you try searching the word `memoir` in the `biblatex` manual?

Comment: See the example on page 99 of the `biblatex` manual, you'll need to add `\addcontentsline` to it as well. I have no idea why `biblatex` is not just following the class definitions

Comment: @daleif `biblatex`'s default headings already use some of the interfaces `memoir` provide. (To be fair I don't know when exactly the `memoir` headings in `biblatex` were implemented and what interface `memoir` offered at that point. Maybe at the it was implemented one could have gone further; or maybe not.) I had a quick look at the current state and it would be cool to use `\bibsection`, but AFAICS that does not accept an (optional) argument to change the heading title, so it is not quite enough for what `biblatex` needs. ...

Comment: ... If you think `biblatex` could improve, don't hesitate to head over to https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues and share your suggestions.

Comment: Off-topic, but `(\cite{einstein})` would more elegantly be written as `\parencite{einstein}` (or even better if that is your default mode of citation: `\autocite{einstein}`). `hyperref=auto,` is the default setting and can be dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\ordinal\relax

% Bibliography
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    hyperref=auto,
    style=authoryear,
    backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

% TOC title
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\HUGE\textit{Contents}}

% Chapter
\usepackage{fmtcount}
%\setlength{\cftchapterindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Numberstring{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfillnum}[1]{\hspace{10pt}\huge#1\hfill\strut\par}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{}
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\hfil\Large\emph{#1}\hfil\strut\huge\par\hfill}
\newcommand\finalchapternumberline[1]{\nopagebreak\huge\hfill}
% Document

% Patch
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\blx@head@bibliography}[1][\bibname]{\chapter *{#1}%
    \if@twoside \markboth {\abx@MakeMarkcase {#1}}{\abx@MakeMarkcase {#1}}%
    \else \markright {\abx@MakeMarkcase {#1}}\fi
    \ifmemoirbibintoc {%
       \phantomsection 
       \addcontentsline {toc}{chapter}{\protect\finalchapternumberline{}The References}%
       }%
       {}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents*
    \chapter*[Introduction]{Introduction}
    \chapter{The First Chapter}
    "Everything is relative" (\cite{einstein}).
    \chapter{The Second Chapter}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: TOC]

I also modified other things to get better centering.

Comment: ah sorry I had not seen you provided sample.bib so I worked without it but it changed everything so now we have to prevent the `\addcontentsline` from `\printbibliography`...

Comment: Note that that might end up pointing to the wrong page as `\printbibliography` may execute a `\cleardoublepage` first. It is better to control the header and the data it adds to the toc.

Comment: @daleif ok. will update.

Comment: update done.  Next time I will check that question provided `sample.bib` file to avoid working without really activating biblatex...

Comment: My code prints "The References" in the TOC and uses `\bibname` aka Bibliography on page 9 but it is easy to modify the patch to do whatever one wants.

Comment: Erh, you can just use `\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \markboth{#1}{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberline{}#1}
}` per my comment to the OP (it is the code from the `biblatex` manual page 99) with `\addcontentsline` added

Comment: `\blx@head@bibliography` is an internal command. The official interface to (re)define bib headings is `\defbibheading`. So I'd say `\defbibheading{bibliography}{...}` would be more appropriate here.

Comment: ok @daleif I did a "like" for your comment to show as it provides important improvement. I will ponder if I should edit my answer, which illustrates simply what one can do when one does not read user manuals but only TeX macro traces.

Comment: @moewe Thanks for important to user clarification. Upvoted your comment to try to let it show preferentially.